# ¿Como posicionar input radio dentro o encima de una imagen?

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap

buenas tardes comunidad, un saludo tengan todos. El motivo por el cual acudo a vosotros es el siguiente.
Como puediera poner input radios encima de una imagen, os comento mas en prefundidad, tengo un software médico escrito con php ,html,bostrap y el la sección de  historia clinica me gustría poner una imagen del cuerpo humano para que los profesionales medicos marquen la zoan de dolor cuando esten pasando la explorasion fisica al peciente asi de esta manera al recuperar la info quedaria reflejada que zona es la idicada para realizar el tratamiento , para eso necesitaria mostrar inputs por cada parte del cuerpo , pero e buscado por la red y no encontrado nada la respecto, teneis alguna idea de como pudiera hacerlo ?

Comment: Tu pregunta pudiera terminar cerrada pues tiene problemas de formato, sugiero leas [ask] y trates de mejorarla

Comment: Tienes puntos de reputación que indica que conoces la funcionalidad del sitio, agrega el código que has intentado y no utilices negrilla.

Comment: El problema es que no tengo codigo echo , es una pregunta que lanzo , itente mapear una imagen  pero los imputs radios no me salen

Comment: @YandryHernández eso es un avance y es bueno y sirve de mucho que lo agregues para que así la comunidad sepa desde donde ayudarte